# What does =++C5 mean in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking at a template spreadsheet which, among other things has

```
=++C5*EXP(-C7*C6)
```

as a formula. What does the `++` in `++C5` do?

If it doesn't do anything, can you think of a reason where it *would* do something? I would be very surprised if the template has mistakes/redundancies.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. It parses to (nothing) + (nothing) + C5*EXP(-C7*C6)

Comment: What would be a reason someone would write that then? It's template that I wouldn't expect to have mistakes.

Comment: I don't see any reason. Similar to other languages it look like an incrementation but in an Excel spreadsheet I don't see any reason. Moreover excel notify you when you write such a thing in a cell.

Comment: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/10/18/how-to-start-a-formula/

Comment: ^This. Thanks Siddharth!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything. It's exactly the same than to write `=C5*EXP(-C7*C6)`